# There was an error communicating with the database. Please contact the application administrator

Tags: mysql, tomcat, orbeon

i just running Bitnami Tomcat 8.5.24-2 in the google Cloud. and i need to connect to mysql and i do following as orbeon steps:

1. Create a new user orbeon with password orbeon and new schema orbeon.
2. Create the tables used for Orbeon Forms in the orbeon schema.
3. Download mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar and copy it in xampp\tomcat\lib.
   4  Edit Tomcat's server.xml, and within the for Orbeon Forms adding a `<Resource>`

   ```
       auth="Container"
       type="javax.sql.DataSource"

       initialSize="3"
       maxActive="10"
       maxIdle="10"
       maxWait="30000"

       poolPreparedStatements="true"
       testOnBorrow="true"
       validationQuery="select 1"

       username="orbeon"
       password="orbeon"
       url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orbeon?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8"/>
   ```

and for Valve in same file

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
       directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log"
       suffix=".txt"
       pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>
<property as="xs:string"
          name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.orbeon.library.*"
          value="mysql"/>
```

and on Orbeon `properties-local.xml`

```
<properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">

    <property as="xs:string"
              me="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*"
              value="mysql"/>
</properties>
```

Comment: Any Idea how can i connect to Mysql ????

Comment: Your XML above shows a `<property>` element in server.xml. That wouldn't work. Put in in properties-local.xml instead. If things still don't work, check all log files: Tomcat's logs, as well as orbeon.log, for errors.

Comment: Also see [this thread](http://discuss.orbeon.com/There-was-an-error-communicating-with-the-database-Please-contact-the-application-administrator-td4663087.html) where this question was cross-posted.